# Cygwin: Installing vim with ruby support

Tags: ruby, vim, cygwin

The big picture here is I'm using [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) and trying to run [command t](https://github.com/wincent/command-t) on cygwin.

The command t documentation says:

```
1. Vim compiled with Ruby support

You can check for Ruby support by launching Vim with the --version switch:

  vim --version

If "+ruby" appears in the version information then your version of Vim has
Ruby support.

Another way to check is to simply try using the :ruby command from within Vim
itself:

  :ruby 1

If your Vim lacks support you'll see an error message like this:

  E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version
```

When I run `:ruby 1`, I see this error:

```
E448: Could not load library function rb_assoc_new
E266: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Ruby library could not be loaded.
```

I'm surprised that when I googled for `rb_assoc_new`, nothing useful turns up.   What ruby package is this in?  When I check the version, I see this:

```
$ vim --version | grep ruby
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
```

Is `+ruby/dyn` significantly different from `+ruby`?

Also:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-cygwin]
```

Comment: Are all your components installed in Cygwin? Seen plenty of confusion when part of the chain is windows and part cygwin.

Comment: @AIG I believe so.  Both vim and ruby are at least.

Comment: You need `+ruby` not `+ruby/dyn`. You will need to install the `ruby-devel` package and compile Vim yourself.

Comment: @romainl previously it was working. It seems like a bug. better to report it at the cygwin mailing [list](https://cygwin.com/lists.html).

Comment: @AmeyaVS, good move.

Comment: @romainl any way to link to your report?  Probably not since it's a mailing list.

Comment: I didn't report anything. Maybe @AmeyaVS did?

Comment: Hi @romainl, sorry didn't get time to report the bug, but for temporary measure install the `*vim-8.0.1157-1` package from the `setup.exe` for me this version is working without any issues.

Comment: @romainl sorry for the delay but finally sent out an e-mail to the mailing list about the bug, you can follow the progress [here](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2017-12/msg00129.html).

Comment: No update on this? Looks like no one responded to your thread @AmeyaVS. :(

Comment: @Adrian yes it seems the thread was completely ignored. Maybe someone else could also notify in the cygwin mailing list about this issue. I tried my best to provide as much details as possible.

Comment: It's too bad I can't just respond to that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby support fixed in Cygwin ViM: [vim-8.0.1486-1](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fvim%2Fvim-8.0.1486-1&grep=vim).

You should also have the latest `ruby` installed: [ruby-2.3.6](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fruby%2Fruby-2.3.6-1&grep=ruby),
and also do not forget to rebuild the dynamic library for [command-t](https://github.com/wincent/command-t).

**Note:** You can find the discussion on the cygwin mailing list [here](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-02/msg00101.html).